# Ubuntu freezes immediately after log in

Tags: 18.04, power-management, shutdown, battery

I have two main issues going on:

1. Whenever I start my computer fresh after shutdown, it freezes right after logging in. The time of freezing is not constant, but it's within a minute or two from logging in. If this happens, I have to shut down the laptop (force shutdown) manually. I have to do this at least ten times, and then it stays on, with no issues. Something to do with the power supply?
2. Whenever my battery dies, the computer shuts down rather than going to sleep. So when I plug in the adapter and start the computer, it starts fresh. Not sure why it's doing this, I am losing all the programs running

I am using Dell Laptop with just one OS, Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: 2) "Sleep" requires power. Power loss *for any reason* will kill the sleeping session, all work lost, and the system must reboot fresh. You seem to be describing expected behavior for "sleep". Don't let your battery die.

Comment: This site works best if you ask one question at a time. It's unlikely that a future user will have both of your exact problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may have found a temp solution, not sure if this is right fix!
I removed all my nvidia driver using `apt-get remove nvidia-*`
However Ubuntu autoinstalled Intel driver for video, but I have Nvidia. It's weird the issue went off, not sure if I wanted to do `ubuntu-drvers autoinstall`
Will wait and see if the issue replicates and install appropriate video driver.